# How to handle a ViewStub in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, viewstub

A few days ago I came across the new Twitter API (ver. 3.1.1) and I tried to copy the effect I saw in the tweets list.

Unfortunately I'm a new user and I can't post images, so I'm trying to explain what I'm talking about

There is List of tweets (a listview) and you can interact with them by a longKeyPressed.
As soon as you click, the selected Item disappear and a new item appears. in this new Item there are the available option for the selected tweet (retweet, favourite, etc...)

I tried to make a copy of this functionality but I have a couple of issue that I can't figure out.

Let's assume that we use a ViewStub in order to optimize the listView, this is the layout of the row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/twitter_stub"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/twitter_actions"
    android:layout="@layout/twitter_swipe_actions" />
<LinearLayout android:id="theOneWhichHasToDisappear">
  .....the row of the listVIew.....
<LinearLayout>
```

When I try to set the visibility of the linearLayout ("theOneWhichHasToDisappear") to gone, everithing is cool, and here it is

```
v.findViewById(R.id.theOneWitchHasToDisappear).setVisibility(View.GONE);
//inflating the stubview
ViewStub stub =  (ViewStub) v.findViewById(R.id.twitter_stub);
View inflated = stub.inflate();
```

but unfortunately I can't keep the proper height of the item (the height is not supposed to change after the new inflating).
Otherwise, when I replace an item on the list, other Items change!!! for example when I click on the first item of the list (the first tweet) the number 1 changes the view, but the numbers 4, 8, 12 etc.. change as well!

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the ViewStub and layout on one RelativeLayout, this way the size doesn't changes.

The change on the other items is about the view reuse by ListView. You must check on your Adapter's getView() method that only on the selected view you show the stub, on the others you must hide it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the height is still changing even if I set a RelativeLayout which contains the stub and the row layout!!

Comment: Did you set the height on the RelativeLayout?

Comment: The Height of my RelativeLayout is set to  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: If you can put the real height on the RelativeLayout the height will not change when it's contents change.

Comment: WHat do you mean with "real height"? I can't set the height manually, cause it is an item of a listview. Of course I could get the height programmatically before che content change but it seems not to be a great solution.

Comment: Instead of putting wrap_content, use the height of the item, like 100dip. Or you could not use a viewstub and keep the other item in the layout but keep invisible (not gone) so the height will not change.

Comment: The final solution is: I can use a viewStub, but as you said above I have to keep the layout INVISIBLE (not GONE). thanks.